# Rewrite URL APACHE 2.4.9 htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am using apache 2.4.9

i want to rewrite a url in htaccess

```
https://localhost/balance.php/editbalance
```

when i enter above url it should be displayed like below

```
https://localhost/editerapi/editbalance
```

i have tried this but its not working

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^editerapi/?$    balance.php   [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/editerapi [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+)/? balance.php/$1 [L] #POST
```

MY REWRITE ENGINE IS ON

the below code of hiding php extension is working

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^editerapi((?:/.*)?)$ balance.php$1 [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the new URL in the browser's bar, you must *redirect* instead of rewrite, e.g. use the [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

```
RewriteRule ^balance\.php/(.*)$ /editerapi/$1 [R,L]
```

Now the client requests the new URL `/editerapi/...`, and you must rewrite to

```
RewriteRule ^editerapi/(.*)$ /balance.php/$1 [L]
```

To prevent a rewrite loop, a [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) is added. Now the redirect only happens, when `balance.php` is requested

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} " /balance\.php/"
```

---

Everything put together gives

```
RewriteRule ^editerapi/(.*)$ /balance.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} " /balance\.php/"
RewriteRule ^balance\.php/(.*)$ /editerapi/$1 [R,L]
```